# Can't figure out "unable to import [module]" in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've recently swapped drives on my notebook and decided on a completely fresh install. When setting up VSCode for a new python project, I installed the latest version from python's website, added the appropriate environment variable to the path, removed the length cap for the pathname too, and all that.
[python environment variable added to Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqKnc.png)
But still, every time I import NumPy or any other module for that matter, it throws an error saying "unable to import [module]".
[vscode error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tv9A2.png)
I don't know what else to do, VSCode even recognizes the interpreter (see image 3).
[python interpreter selected in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vozrJ.png)
Tried setting up a venv aswell, end up getting the same error.

Comment: Is numpy installed? Is it installed in the environment that vs code is configured to use?

Comment: yes, when I use the command "pip install numpy" it returns that "the requirements are already met", and shows the folder and version

Comment: So you ran `pip install numpy` from the command line? Was this using the global `pip` or the `pip` for the venv? If you are installing with the global pip, you need to be sure to activate the virtual environment first.

Comment: I tried in both cases. Both failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I normally set up a project and it always works.

(open directory in VSCode)

Within the VSCode Terminal

```sh
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
```

At this time vscode should automatically detect that there is a new virtualenv and ask you to use it.

If it doesn't you can use the CMD+Shift+P (CTRL+Shift+P) search for "Select Python Interpreter" and specify the path.

Comment: Did this and it worked for numpy, but for other modules it throws the same error even after I installed them in the venv using pip

Comment: after rebooting VSCode it appears to be working properly. So far, so good!

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Numpy in the virtual environment (if you are using one)?

Try to list your installed packages in vscode terminal

```
python -m pip list
```

If numpy does not appear, install numpy with:

```
python -m pip install numpy
```

Does it work when you run the code? Or is this just a pylint problem?

Comment: Yes, numpy is installed in the venv. I tried creating a new venv and it finally found numpy automatically, but now it's failing for other modules (even with them installed in the venv).
It doesn't work because it stops on this import error right at the beginning